# Apache server type in response header

Tags: apache

I don't want the server type to be shown in the response headers.
I've tried to add this to httpd.conf, as I saw in many answers:

```
ServerSignature Off

ServerTokens Prod
```

But I still see "Server: Apache" in the response:

[image]

Can I remove the "Apache" from the response?

---

### Update

---

Also tried this:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

Header unset Server

Header unset X-Powered-By
```

But I got the same response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove the header `Server: Apache` unless you modify the source code and recompile Apache. And if you do, still it may be not so difficult to find out which server software you are running.

Make a search for "webserver fingerprinting", you will find about HTTP header response ordering, answers to malformed requests and other ways to discover which server you are running. Spend your time securing your application instead of trying to achieve this obfuscation.

From [Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#servertokens):

> Setting ServerTokens to less than minimal is not recommended because
>   it makes it more difficult to debug interoperational problems. Also
>   note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make
>   your server more secure.